# SVG CSS Animation for IE and Safari not working

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

Hi guys so im hitting a brick wall with 2 issues:

1. IE the pulse in the middle works but not the circular progress
2. In safari (win) the curcluar progress does not work
3. Firefox and Chrome work fine

Any ideas? i literally only have a few hours ot crack this.

NOTE: You have to click on the circle in order to start the animation. Thanks in advance for any help in cracking this for me.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0pkqk5r0/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="loader">
    <svg height="80" width="80" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
        <path id="back" d="M0,100 a100,100 0 1 0 200,0 a100,100 0 1 0 -200,0" fill="#FF1251" stroke="#FF1251" stroke-width="20" />
        <path id="ring" d="M100,0 a100,100 0 0 1 0,200 a100,100 0 0 1 0,-200,0" fill="none" stroke="#FF1251" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="629" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dashoffset="629" />
    </svg>
    <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* temp */
body {
    background: #072237;
}

h3, p {
    color: #ffffff;
}


#loader {
    position: relative;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#ring.active {
    -webkit-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
    -o-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
    -ms-animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
    animation: load 6s 1 forwards;
}

#circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle.active {
    background: #FF1251;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
    -moz-animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
    -o-animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
    -ms-animation:  pulse 1.2s 3;
    animation: pulse 1.2s 3;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    -o-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

/* Pulse */
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    20% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    40% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
    }
}

/* Loading */

@-webkit-keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes load {
    80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: won't be able to help w/ ie but for safari you have to add constructor specific (`-webkit-`) before `transform` in the pulse animation

Comment: I already have the -website- before transform no?

Comment: Ahh great that worked, any ideas on the load one?

Comment: do you mean the red filling circle? Can't reproduce your issue with Safari 7.1.2

Comment: Yea the main border / stroke that goes around the main outside, in safari just seems to do the pulse and not the loading effect out the outside. 5.1.7 safari, maybe ill update.

Comment: Ahh seems 5.1.7 is latest on windows no?

Comment: Yea will update now, but you say the loading works fine on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand animations will work on:

- IE10+
- Safari 9+

Use HTML+TIME for older versions of IE:

```
.time {behavior: url(#default#time2)}

<div id="circle" class="time" begin="0" end="2" timeAction="style">
```

Use longhand for older versions of Safari:

```
#circle.active {
 -webkit-animation-name: pulse;

 -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
}
```

**References**

- [Introduction to CSS3 Animations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/12/06/introduction-to-css3-animations.aspx)
- [What's New in Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Safari CSS Visual Effects Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Introduction.html)
- [Internet Explorer 10 Guide for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673549.aspx)
- [Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj819730.aspx)
- [HTML+TIME Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-HTMLplusTIME)
- [time2 Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533611)
- [Using the HTML+TIME Document Object Model (DOM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533123)
- [Animated DHTML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263971)
- [BUG: HTML+TIME Code Fails Inside an Element Behavior](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/298397)